# Setting facecolor for matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

What method can I use to set the colour (to `'none'`) for a axes of type `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`

According to the documentation:

> *subplot_kw* : dict
>       Dict with keywords passed to the
>       :meth:`~matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot` call used to
>       create each subplots.

So the variable is `fc` (see doc [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html)) and this should work right?

```
f, a = plt.subplots(1, 4, subplot_kw={'fc':'none'})
```

But I get the error

> AttributeError: Unknown property fc

I have also tried setting the colour for the indvidual axes

```
ax.set_axis_bgcolor("none")
```

but it is ignored.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `f, a = plt.subplots(1, 4, subplot_kw={'fc':'none'})` does not throw an error and display 4 subplots with no background color. I am using matplotlib v. 2.0.2

Comment: In addition to @DizietAsahi 's comment (which is entirely correct), also `ax.set_axis_bgcolor("none")` would work as expected. It is however deprecated as of version 2.0.2 and can be replaced by `ax.set_facecolor("none")`.